# How to determine how long my Windows 10 computer has been "inactive", from the command line, without third-party software?

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to figure out a terminal command which allows me to get a timestamp indicating when the computer was last "active", without installing any third-party software.

I define "active" in this way (both points must be satisfied):

- The lock screen/mode is ***not*** enabled.
- Any key on the keyboard is pressed, or the mouse is clicked or moved.

The purpose is for me to know how long it's been since I was last "actively using the computer", which in turn will be used for a certain security measure which isn't relevant to this specific question.

Is this kept track of by Windows? As usual, searching yields nothing, but that doesn't mean anything; countless "gold nuggets" are hidden in computers which only a handful of people know about.

Comment: I recommend you that this would be easy if you move on from CMD to a programming language like C. In that case, I can give you a script for that.

Answer (score 0):

Two options spring to mind.

You could use the `quser` command which will give you the idle time of a specific user.

(or)

You can use the PowerShell code documented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15846912).